# How to access an enum's state from another function

Tags: swift, function, enums, state

I have code that is making a randomly generating maze and basically the maze is made with a grid (array) with each grid cell having 4 variables (up, down, left, right) of type bool which all refer to the cell walls. The true or false of the walls are randomly chosen. If a wall is true then there is a wall placed, however is false, then there is no wall there.

However, all of this happens in the `Maze` class and within the `GameScene` class. Within the `GameScene.swift`, I have created an `enum wallSides` with the states `upSide, downSide, leftSide, rightSide, noSide' (basically referring to which side wall of the cell the user taps on):

```
enum wallSides {
    case upSide, downSide, leftSide, rightSide, noSide
}
```

I use these states in `func ConvertLocationPointtoGridPosition` which takes in a `CGPoint` location and converts and returns it as x, y integers (to find which cell it is in the grid). The function also uses the location it takes in to find out which wall of the cell the location point was at using the `upSide, downSide, leftSide, rightSide, noSide` states and returns `wallSide`:

```
func ConvertLocationPointToGridPosition(location: CGPoint) -> (x: Int, y: Int, side: wallSides) {
    var xPoint: CGFloat
    var yPoint: CGFloat
    xPoint = location.x / CGFloat(tileSize)
    yPoint = location.y / CGFloat(tileSize)
    let yPointRemainder = yPoint.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
    let xPointRemainder = xPoint.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
    var wallSide: wallSides

    if yPointRemainder < 0.2 && xPointRemainder < 0.8 && xPointRemainder > 0.2 {
        wallSide = .downSide
    } else if yPointRemainder > 0.8 && xPointRemainder < 0.8 && xPointRemainder > 0.2 {
        wallSide = .upSide
    } else if xPointRemainder < 0.2 && yPointRemainder < 0.8 && yPointRemainder > 0.2 {
        wallSide = .leftSide
    } else if  xPointRemainder > 0.8 && yPointRemainder < 0.8 && yPointRemainder > 0.2 {
        wallSide = .rightSide
    } else {
        wallSide = .noSide
    }//end of if-then

    return(Int(xPoint), Int(yPoint), wallSide)
}
```

What I am trying to do is within the `func TouchesBegan` where if the node which the user taps is a wall, and "if the wall state is rightSide, then do something" but I am not sure how to access the enum's states and variables from the `fConvertLocationPointToGridPosition`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //actually user tapping a wall
    //send a message that the wall has been tapped
    let touch = touches.first!              // Get the first touch
    let location  = touch.location(in: self) //find the location of the touch in the view
    let nodeAtPoint = atPoint(location) //find the node at that location
    if nodeAtPoint.name == "mazeWall" {
        ConvertLocationPointToGridPosition(location: location)
        //self.removeChildren(in: [self.atPoint(location)])

        //if  side == wallSides.downSide {
            //code
        //}
    }//end of nodeAtPoint = mazeWall if-then statement
}
```

Please help me out on how how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correct, ure issue is accessing multiple return values. try this

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //actually user tapping a wall
    //send a message that the wall has been tapped
    let touch = touches.first!              // Get the first touch
    let location  = touch.location(in: self) //find the location of the touch in the view
    let nodeAtPoint = atPoint(location) //find the node at that location
    if nodeAtPoint.name == "mazeWall" {

        let (x, y, side) = ConvertLocationPointToGridPosition(location: location)
        //self.removeChildren(in: [self.atPoint(location)])

        if  side == wallSides.downSide {
        //code
        }
    }//end of nodeAtPoint = mazeWall if-then statement
}
```

Another version.

```
let position = ConvertLocationPointToGridPosition(location: location)
print("side: \(position.2)")
```